# A short cut for "Printf.fprintf"

Tags: printing, ocaml

As I use a lot `Printf.fprintf stdout ...` in my programs, I would like to rename it by a shorter function. So I write:

```
let p = Printf.fprintf stdout
```

And I would hope `p "%s" "string"` works. However, the compilation gives an error:

```
File "lib/utility.ml", line 27, characters 8-29:
Error: The type of this expression, ('_a, out_channel, unit) format -> '_a,
       contains type variables that cannot be generalized
```

Does anyone have an idea to rename it so that the application could be as simple as possible?

Comment: For this specific case you can just use `Printf.printf`, right?

Comment: `let p = Printf.fprintf stdout;; p "%s" "string"` works for me

Comment: The `'_a` is weak polymorphism, which if fine, but if it is an error it usually means you need to eta-expand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will work if you eta-expand your definition:

```
let p fmt = Printf.fprintf stdout fmt
```